# @Local interface with many realisation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have @Local interface

```
@Local
public interface IRepo
{
```

and two realisation, but **only 1** bean realisation

```
@Stateless(name = "RepoBean")
public class RepoBean implements IRepo
{
```

second

```
public class SimpleRepo implements ILogRepositoryIRepo
{
```

and inject it ti my Web service using

```
   @EJB(name = "RepoBean")
   private IRepo repository;
```

And it's works well on `jboss` and on `WebLogic`. But on `GlassFish 3.1.1` I get Error (while deploying)

```
  Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=RepoBean,Local 3.x interface =com.company.IRepo,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session because there are 2 ejbs in the application with interface com.company.IRepo.
```

But I have only 1 *ejb* realisation.
Any ideas? May be I can use some deployment-desriptor or something else.
`EJB 3.0, Java EE 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really didn't understand what you're trying to do, but if you have two beans that implement the same business interface, you'll have to use the 'beanName' attribute as follows:

```
@EJB(beanName = "RepoBean")
private IRepo repository;
```

-- UPDATE

Look at this: [java.net/node/702013](http://java.net/node/702013). There is a bug issue to this problem: [java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11684](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11684)

Seems like this only occurs with EJB-in-WAR packaging. In ejb jar doesn't happen.

Comment: I have 1 bean. Two realisations. I have two databases - Oracle database (for it I am using bean) and XML database (for it I am using JAXB marshalling)

Comment: I agree with this.  In the class that depends on `IRepo`, your `@EJB` annotation should use `beanName` instead of `name`.  I think that's why the server is complaining that you have 2 impls.  It also seems like it thinks you are declaring a 2nd impl.  An alternative is to just remove `name` entirely from both annotations.  If you have 1 impl, it's not needed. 

Here's an example: http://bit.ly/PnKaNs

And of course always need to check assumptions.  Have you done a total clean on the project and searched for references to `IRepo`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Glassfish is more right than JBoss and WebLogic, Business-Bean-Classes should all have their own EJB-Local-Interface.

I Guess WL or JBoss will give you a warning instead of an error.